# WKWebView Camera Preview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a URL that needs to display a camera preview, whereas I display the said URL using `WKWebView`.

However, upon checking the camera preview is not working using`WKWebView`, but it quite works when I open the URL using Safari, it's just that the preview only captures a single frame, from there, the image in the preview doesn't change.

Anyone here who tried doing this `WKWebView`? One workaround that I am thinking of is to use **JS bridge**.

Comment: Yes, I have same face this problem from WKWebView, So, Please use in that SFSafariViewController. It properly works for me and yes above issue, it happens to when you load some url. So, I think SFSafariViewController is a better way to use it.

Comment: Thank you, @nipa. However, I cannot use SFSafariViewController since we still support iOS 8, anad SFSafariViewController minimum iOS version is 9 :(